# JMeter - What kind of extractor should be used for a PageSessionID request parameter?

Tags: jmeter, sessionid

I've been using JMeter to test the functionality of a site. A particular publishing action generates a different PageSessionId for every user when running the request.

I'm a bit of a novice with JMeter, and it's clear that there needs to be an extractor to help parse in the user-generated sessionid's for these requests. Any ideas on what extractor would be most helpful for this and its likely set-up?

Request Parameter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OboZq.png

Request Response: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpuO8.png

Comment: Could  you include a sample response with the sessionid?

Answer (score 0):

If the response is in HTML format, you could use one of following Post Processors to extract the sessionId.

1. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
2. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor)
3. [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor)

If the response is in JSON format, you could use of following Post Processors to extract the sessionId.

1. [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
2. [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)

In this short video on managing the sessions, I have demonstrated use of few post processors. [video](https://youtu.be/dlnVLv4QXh8)

Comment: Hi Janesh, Thanks for those resources. An image of the response can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpuO8.png

Comment: Thanks for sharing the image. You have selected Request --> Request Body.  We need response  body

Answer (score 0):

You're showing the request and in order to be able to suggest the most suitable option we need to see the response (where this dynamic value is returned)

From high level perspective:

- For [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) - [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)
- For [XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/) and [XHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) (and in certain cases HTML) - [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor)
- For [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) - [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)
- For anything else -  [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor)